# Jquery validation sums errors

Tags: jquery

This is my Jquery script. if i click the button it is checking if everyting is filled in valid. But if i click the button 10 times i get 10 times the same errors. I am wondering if i can make those erros empty again, so you only see the latest click event. thanks in forehand

```
var toevoegenknop=$('<button>Toevoegen</button>').appendTo(main);
        toevoegenknop.click(function() {

            var huisnummer = input_huisnummer.val();
            var naam = input_naam.val();
            var aantalpers = input_aantalpers.val();
            var comfort = input_comfort.val();
            var bouwjaar = input_bouwjaar.val();

            verwerken = true;
            if(huisnummer<1 || huisnummer>500){
                foutmelding1=$('<p>Er moet een geldig huisnummer ingevuld worden</p>').appendTo(main);
                verwerken = false;
            }
            if(naam==''){
                foutmelding2=$('<p>Er moet een geldige naam ingevuld worden</p>').appendTo(main);
                verwerken = false;
            }
            if(aantalpers<1 || aantalpers>20){
                foutmelding3=$('<p>Er moet een geldig aantal personen ingevuld worden</p>').appendTo(main);
                verwerken = false;
            }
            if(comfort<1 || comfort>3){
                foutmelding4=$('<p>Comfort kan allen becijferd worden met een getal tussen 1 en 3</p>').appendTo(main);
                verwerken = false;
            }
            if(bouwjaar<1900 || bouwjaar>2014){
                foutmelding5=$('<p>Er moet een geldig bouwjaar ingevuld worden</p>').appendTo(main);
                verwerken = false;
            }
```

Comment: when everything is empty i click the button and it gives me all my 5 errors. but when i click the button again it gives 5 the same errors again, instead of just seeing 5 errors i now see 10! everytime i click it it gives me the errors which it is supposed to give, instead of clearing the previous errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var toevoegenknop=$('<button>Toevoegen</button>').appendTo(main);
        toevoegenknop.click(function() {

            var huisnummer = input_huisnummer.val();
            var naam = input_naam.val();
            var aantalpers = input_aantalpers.val();
            var comfort = input_comfort.val();
            var bouwjaar = input_bouwjaar.val();
            var error_code = '';

            $('<div id="errors_div"></div>').appendTo(main);

            verwerken = true;
            if(huisnummer<1 || huisnummer>500){
                foutmelding1='<p>Er moet een geldig huisnummer ingevuld worden</p>';//.appendTo(main);
                error_code += foutmelding1 + '<br>';
                verwerken = false;
            }
            if(naam==''){
                foutmelding2='<p>Er moet een geldige naam ingevuld worden</p>';//.appendTo(main);
                error_code += foutmelding2 + '<br>';
                verwerken = false;
            }
            if(aantalpers<1 || aantalpers>20){
                foutmelding3='<p>Er moet een geldig aantal personen ingevuld worden</p>';//.appendTo(main);
                error_code += foutmelding3 + '<br>';
                verwerken = false;
            }
            if(comfort<1 || comfort>3){
                foutmelding4='<p>Comfort kan allen becijferd worden met een getal tussen 1 en 3</p>';//.appendTo(main);
                error_code += foutmelding4 + '<br>';
                verwerken = false;
            }
            if(bouwjaar<1900 || bouwjaar>2014){
                foutmelding5='<p>Er moet een geldig bouwjaar ingevuld worden</p>';//.appendTo(main);
                error_code += foutmelding5 + '<br>';
                verwerken = false;
            }
            $('#errors_div').html(error_code);
        });
```

I added a variable `error_code`, then on each condition/validation, I've added your Error messages as string to the `error_code` variable, appending it in javascript manner.

Then after the conditions have been checked, I've appended the final list of errors to the `main`....
Your code wasn't working because you were Appending the errors to the main. Appending simple adds, while html or text can replace the contents. Append doesn't replace.